# Bug on a custom C++ class

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, operator-overloading, overloading

I need help on finding the problem using a custom c++ class to manage 3D positions. Here is the relevant code from the class

```
  Punto operator+(Punto p){
    return Punto(this->x + p.x, this->y + p.y, this->z + p.z);
  }

  Punto operator+(Punto *p){
    return Punto(this->x + p->x, this->y + p->y, this->z + p->z);
  }

  Punto operator-(Punto p){
    return Punto(this->x - p.x, this->y - p.y, this->z - p.z);
  }

  Punto operator-(Punto *p){
    return Punto(this->x - p->x, this->y - p->y, this->z - p->z);
  }

  Punto *operator=(Punto p){
    this->x = p.x;
    this->y = p.y;
    this->z = p.z;
    return this;
  }

  Punto *operator=(Punto *p){
    this->x = p->x;
    this->y = p->y;
    this->z = p->z;
    return this;
  }
```

I'm using it here like this:

```
p = fem->elementoFrontera[i]->nodo[0] - fem->elementoFrontera[i]->nodo[1];
```

Where nodo[i] is a Punto*, and it compiles fine, but when I try to do:

```
p = fem->elementoFrontera[i]->nodo[0] + fem->elementoFrontera[i]->nodo[1];
```

The compiler says:

> In member function `void
>   mdTOT::pintarElementosFrontera()':
>   error: invalid operands of types`
>   Punto*' and `Punto*' to binary`
>   operator+'

Comment: Can we get the constructor and .h code?

Comment: Punto(double _x, double _y, double _z){
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    z = _z;
  }

  Punto(Punto *v){
    x = v->x;
    y = v->y;
    z = v->z;
  }

  Punto(const Punto &v){
    x = v.x;
    y = v.y;
    z = v.z;
  }

Comment: Confusion like this makes an excellent case for avoiding operator overloading...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one compiles fine because you can subtract pointers in C/C++, but not add pointers. But in any case it doesn't do what you need - it doesn't use your overloaded operator. Since your operators are defined in a class, you need to operate on class instances, not on pointers. So, change to something like

```
Punto p = *(fem->elementoFrontera[i]->nodo[0]) + *(fem->elementoFrontera[i]->nodo[1]);
```

Another thing - you should use class references, not values, in operator definition. E.g.

```
 Punto& operator+(const Punto& p) {
```

EDIT. To simplify the code, you can create an accessor function, like this:

```
const Punto& NodoRef(int i, int j) {
  return *(fem->elementoFronteria[i]->Nodo[j]);
}
```

and then your code becomes as clean as

```
p = NodoRef(i,0) + NodoRef(i,1);
```

The NodoRef may be defined in your fem class, or outside. Just make sure the object fem is alive in the scope where you use the NodoRef.

Comment: Anyway to make it look prettier? I mean, that's ugly to be deferencing code on each operation, don't you think?

Comment: It's a matter of taste. I prefer explicit code and no hidden magic. If I have a pointer, I know need to dereference it before applying any operations.

Comment: Technically, you can declare out-of-class operator+ with 2 parameters, defined on pointers to Punto. But it needs to return an object. So, it's ugly: the + operator doesn't return the same type as operands. I would not recommend doing this.

Comment: Regarding how to make it prettier: I would create an accessor function that returns a const reference to a Punto. Let me update the answer...

Answer (score 0):

The first version works because "`-`" does normal pointer arithmetic in this case, it doesn't use any of your overloaded operators. "`+`" is not defined on normal pointers, so you get an error. To make it use the overloaded version, dereference the first pointer:

```
p = *fem->elementoFrontera[i]->nodo[0] - fem->elementoFrontera[i]->nodo[1];
```

Dereferencing both pointers should also work since you have both types of overloads, but you should change your operator definitions to use const references in this case:

```
Punto operator+(const Punto &p){
   ...
}
```

This way the objects are not copied every time you use "`+`".

Basically you want to do something like this:

```
const Punto operator+(Punto *left, Punto *right); // not allowed
```

But overloading a free function `operator+` that takes two pointers and adds them in a suitable way does not work, because at least one of the parameters needs to be of [enum or class type](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/intrinsic-types.html#faq-26.10). There is no operator overloading for primitive types, and pointers count as such.

Comment: Same here, it's ugly to be deferencing everywhere, any hints on making it look simplier?

Comment: Could you just store Punto objects instead of pointers to them in your elementoFrontera vector? Then the "+" would work as expected...

Comment: The idea is for it to point to some other place where the Punto objects are saved.